# Suitable MySQL benchmark tool

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a benchmark tool that can benchmark MySQL Replication.

- It can connect to multiple replicas and the master. So it does write operations on the master, and reads from slaves.
- It should also be capable for adjusting read (SELECT)/write (UPDATE, DELETE ...) ratio, or change the number of read and number of write.
- The output is expected to be tps or more.

Does anyone can suggest a tool for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know of any benchmarks which perform R/W splitting. This is something you may have to build yourself, but it should be fairly straightforward to modify existing benchmarks as [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html) or the [MySQL Benchmark Suite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-benchmarks.html).

Comment: Thanks Michael! It seems that there is still a gap between the real benchmarks and my expectations. :-) I might need to work on my own solution by implementing them by myself.

Comment: You could try using Mysql Proxy (http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy) to do R/W splitting if that helps. Of course, then you have another system in the way of your DB. However, if you're only concerned about relative results, this may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

use sysbench.. its good..
http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-benchmark-your-system-cpu-file-io-mysql-with-sysbench

-Priyesh

Comment: Please expand on your answer and explain why it's good, quoting relevant portions of the website to answer the question